# Find missing coordinate between three intersecting rectangles in python

Tags: python-3.x, geometry

**Problem**: **11** coordinates of **3** intersecting rectangles are given, Find the missing coordinate?

**Example Input** - (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 3), (6, 3), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 2), (6, 1)

**Example Output** - (5, 1)

**Code**:

```
def coord(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3):
    x4 = y4 = 0
    if x1==x2 or x1==x3:
        if x1==x2:
            x4 = x3
        else:
            x4 = x2
    else:
        x4 = x1
    if y1==y2 or y1==y3:
        if y1==y2:
            y4=y3
        else:
            y4=y2
    else:
        y4=y1
    return [x4, y4]

rect = int(input())
x1 = y1 = 0
final = []
for u in range((4*rect)-1):
    x,y = map(int, input().split())
    final.append([x,y])
for u in range(rect):
    l = coord((final[(u*3)+0][0],final[(u*3)+0][1]),(final[(u*3)+1][0],final[(u*3)+1][1]),(final[(u*3)+2][0],final[(u*3)+2][1]))
    if l in final:
        final.remove(l)
    else:
        print(*l)
        break
```

**Note** - This code is working properly when coordinate are given in a serial way but in question coordinate are given in alternate way.

All **4*rect** coordinates are pairwise distinct.

Comment: It looks like a homework assignment. What have you done to solve it? Please include your code and explain what you are not happy with it.

Comment: Please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Note that every X and Y value should be met **even** number of times (due to axis-aligned rectangle properties).

It is not described whether coinciding vertices might occur, but `11 coordinates` assumes they will be repeated.

So just calculate occurence of every X and Y component (with Counter or with dictionary) and look at odd counter - here `X=5` is met once, `Y=1` is met three times, so `(5,1)` is answer

```
import collections
dx = collections.Counter()
dy = collections.Counter()
final = [[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0], [5, 3], [6, 3], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [4, 2], [6, 1]]
for coord in final:
    dx[coord[0]] += 1
    dy[coord[1]] += 1
for xx in dx:
    if dx[xx] % 2 == 1:
        mx = xx
for yy in dy:
    if dy[yy] % 2 == 1:
        my = yy
print([mx, my])

>>[5, 1]
```